# Homemade riddles

Tags: riddle

I have 3 riddles for you that I got from [here](http://checkbit.ch/2014/09/21/riddles/).

> Riddle 1:
>   I am larger when cold and shrink when warm. You can see me, but you cannot touch me.
>
> Riddle 2:
>   When people need me, they throw me away. when I’m not needed they take me back.
>
> Riddle 3:
>   The more you give me, the richer you get. When you rob me, only you get poorer.

Comment: I assume these riddles have seperate answers?

Comment: good point! yes :) they have separate answers.

Comment: they should,  then, have been 3 separate questions.

Comment: sorry, I'm new in town. And yes, you are right. I put them together, because they are short, but now I know.. and will give my best in the future to separate the questions properly.

Comment: It's ok really :) just so you know. welcome aboard

Comment: gave Star! I like the flow.. there's also meaning to each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the answers are scattered (by the way, you should have asked 3 separate questions):

### 1

> Night

### 2

> Anchor

### 3

> Piggy bank

I do this in the interest of the site being the QnA it is designed to be.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will keep that in mind for future  questions.

Comment: You might consider adding explanations. Like, how does the first one meet the description " I am larger when cold and shrink when warm"???

Comment: @RedCaio It has to do with air

Comment: the air expanding/shrinking? lol. wouldn't it have more to do with the days being longer in the winter?

Comment: @RedCaio Actually, yes. You are right. Apologies for my incorrect response

Answer (score 16):

Number 1

> The empty space in a thermometer

Number 2

> An Anchor

Number 3

> My Savings Account

Comment: Oh, you are a creative person :)

Comment: #2 & #3 are right. #1 made my day, I haven't thought of it this way :)

Answer (score 5):

I see that #1 and #3 have already been answered, but is the answer to #2:

> An anchor

Comment: yes. nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

#1 is tougher. It could be

> a star. [It heats up when contracting](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/workx/starlife/StarpageS_26M.html) then stabilises, then cools and expands into a Red Giant. Feels a bit forced, though.

#2 is

> A boomerang

#3 is

> A piggy bank

Comment: #3 you got it right!

Comment: #2 What I had in mind was something else. But your answer is also right and fits in.

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi updated with a (possibly too forced) answer for #1

Answer (score 2):

Riddle 1:

> Gas

Riddle 2:

> Breath

Riddle 3:

> Bank

Comment: Your answer of riddle 3 is right. Your answer of riddle 1 could have been right, when the first part of the riddle was: "I am larger whan warm and shrink when cold."

Comment: Whoopsy! Read viceversa XD

Answer (score 2):

<s>#1</s>   **(wrong)**

> Sun, that is closer to Earth in winter and further in summer (in boreal hemisphere)

## 1

> night, that is longer when climate is cold, and shorter otherwise

## 2

> a ball, when you need it you kick it away, when you finish to play you take it home

Comment: Technically your answer to #1 is never "cold", and there's no qualifying words to imply that it's larger when something else (ie. the Earth's climate) is cold

Comment: #1 is very very very close. At least the answer somehow depends on your answer

Comment: I made another try for #1. what about number 2?

Comment: #2 might be.. might be.. it does not fit perfectly, but it is a good guess.

Comment: i like your answer of number 2, nice!

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has been marked as right. 
But as my answer is different, I think I shall write :D.

Riddle #1

> Cloud

Riddle #2

> Poop

Riddle #3

> Money-box / Piggy-bank

---

Just enjoy the answers :D

Answer (score 1):

ONE

> A girlfriend

TWO

> An anchor

THREE

> Not sure. Robbing your bank means you get that money, but also lose it, and vice versa. It equals out... so? Again, I'm not sure